# Yii. Dependent Dropdown

Tags: php, yii

I try make dependent select.

My Model

**Region**
id
region

**City**
id
city
region_id

**Customer**
id
region
city
address
phone

In my views(Customer form):

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'region',CHtml::listData(Region::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'region'),
        array(
            'prompt'=>'Select Region',
            'ajax' => array(
                'type' => 'POST', //My method type
                'url' => CController::createUrl('myController/LoadRegions'), //This is my request/ajax URL
                array('id'=>'js:this.value'), //I'm passing the selected dropdonw value.
                'dataType' => 'JSON',
                'success'=>'js:function(data)' //The functionaliy after success
                    . '{'
                    . '    var html="";'
                    . '    $.each(data,function(i,obj)'
                    . '    {'
                    . '         html+="<option value=obj.City_id>"+obj.City_city+"</option>"'
                    . '    });'
                    . '    $("#User_City_id").html(html);' //ID of regions dropdown list
                    . '}'

            )));
    echo CHtml::dropDownList($model,'City_id', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select City'));

    ?>
```

And in my controller(Customer):

```
public function actionLoadRegions()
    {

        $Region_id=$_POST['region'];

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->select=array('Region_id, Region_region');
        $criteria->condition='Region_id='.$Region_id;
        $criteria->order='Region_region';
        $RegionAry= Region::model()->findAll($criteria);

        $ary=array();
        foreach($RegionAry as $i=>$obj)
        {
            $ary[$i]['Region_id']=$obj->Region_id;
            $ary[$i]['Region_region']=$obj->Region_region;
        }
        echo json_encode($ary);
    }
```

But code is not work. Error Object of class Customer could not be converted to string. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This will work

Your Form

```
'success'   => 'js:function(data) {
                     $("#User_City_id").html(data);
               }'
```

Your Controller function

```
public function actionLoadRegions()
    {

        $Region_id=$_POST['region'];

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->select=array('Region_id, Region_region');
        $criteria->condition='Region_id='.$Region_id;
        $criteria->order='Region_region';
        $RegionAry= Region::model()->findAll($criteria);

        $ary=array();
        foreach($RegionAry as $i=>$obj)
        {
            $ary[$i]['Region_id']=$obj->Region_id;
            $ary[$i]['Region_region']=$obj->Region_region;
        }
       echo CHtml::dropDownList('dropdown_name', $selected, $ary);

    }
```

Comment: I try it,but city select is not see

Comment: what error did you get? have you passed $selected value in actionLoadRegions() function if not possible then try to add static value of $selected and try.

Comment: Second select is hide

Answer (score 0):

I am not familier with Yii but I think you are treating a integer variable as a string so that its showing error .

You sure about this-

echo CHtml::dropDownList($model,'City_id', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select City'));

try instead

echo CHtml::dropDownList($model,City_id, array(), array('prompt'=>'Select City'));

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
echo $form->dropDownList(
                $model,
                'state_id', 
                $array,
                array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'ajax' => array(
                            'type' => 'POST',
                            'url' => $this->createUrl('getregions'),
                            'update' => '#Customers_region_id',
                            'data'=>array('state_id'=>'js:this.value')
                        )
                )
        ); ?>
```

but you have to change name of field state_id, update and url on your defining of dropDownList.

maybe it will help.